# Create a report for AWS defining number of instances in use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I would like to create a report that shows the number of instances in use per data center, avg load on servers ( CPU & memory ) , server failures, bandwidth used . Can this be captured with cloud watch in one aggregation or should I create custom report using cloudwatch api ?
Please advise .

Comment: Where is your metadata residing right now? E.g. mappings between instance ids and datacenters?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Right now, I can view the instances by going to each region or using the cloud watch to filter by data centers in the UI Console.

Comment: What do you mean by datacenter in AWS terminology? There is AZ...